# Twisted library library for Google Compute API

Tags: twisted

google has a very good python library for various APIs.

It appears that it's written with blocking calls.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/compute

Has anyone come across/written a Twisted async adapter to this API that you could share?

Thank you greatly in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing using Twisted yet. Just looking over some of the source, there are instances where Futures are used. So there is a good chance an asyncio variant will be made, at which point you should be able to integrate with Twisted.